# How to call a jQuery function on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Based on ajax call I am creating dynamic elements(buttons) on my page, I do need to call another ajax function to set its attribute.

I want to set its data attribute on its creation.

```
<button class="light UserInfo_" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> data.DriverName </button>
```

I have tried below function but its not working.

```
 jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.UserInfo_', function () {
        jQuery(this).encryptIt();
    });
    function encryptIt() {      
        alert('hi');
    };
```

Comment: If you're inserting the element in the callback of an AJAX request can you not just invoke a function which calls `encryptIt()` on the element?

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it after the Ajax call is done? And that is not how you bind method to jQuery....

Comment: ... Why are you calling `object.encryptIt` while `encryptIt` is an independent function? Consider using `call`. / What's the current behavior, and what's the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows.

```
responseJSON:{element: "<input id='n1'>", id: "n1", attr: "value", value="Hi"}

function foo() {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            result = response;                
        }
    });

    return result;
}

var result = foo().done(function(){

  console.log(result.responseJSON)

  $("#mainCont").append(result.responseJSON["element"]);

    $("#"+result.responseJSON["id"]).attr(result.responseJSON["attr"],result.responseJSON["value"])


});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainCont"></div>
```